# S3 creates signed URLs for items that do not exist

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3 presigned URLs are being created for items that do not exist. Is this normal behavior? I would rather know if the item is not going to exist when creating the link, than send users to an error page. Obviously, I can check if the item exists before I create the link, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's difficult to say whether you're doing something wrong when we have no code to look at. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: Just think of the presigned URL as a signed slip of paper saying "you have my permission to download an object with this name, until the expiry time". When the actual request is sent to S3, then S3 will validated the presigned URL, effectively checking your signature against the one on file then permit the request if it is valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. The pre-signed URL is simply a local calculation and signing of a URL. It has no interaction with the S3 service at all.

If you want to ensure that an object exists before you generate a pre-signed URL for it, then you should `head` that object.

Note: you can use pre-signed URLs to upload new objects, which obviously don't yet exist at the time you generate the URL. You might also want to use pre-signed URLs to download objects that don't yet exist, but will at some later date (though I admit this is probably not that common a use case).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, or just so obvious it's expected we know?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific documentation to this effect, but if you treat this pre-signed URL like, say, a filepath of /usr/james/area51/proof.xml, then you can see that there's no guarantee that that file exists, either at the time the reference is taken or at the time it's used to (attempt to) access the file.